# iText7- bookmark is not jumping to a page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

In ASP.NET application I'm using iText7 to create a new pdf with bookmarks. With the following code, I'm able to create a pdf with a number of pages and bookmarks but when I click on the bookmark nothing happens. How do I make reader navigate to related page when one clicks a bookmark.

```
public ActionResult CreatePdf()
{
    byte[] pdfBytes;
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var wri = new PdfWriter(stream))
    using (var pdf = new PdfDocument(wri))
    using (var doc = new Document(pdf))
    {   

        doc.Add(new Paragraph("Working with iText7"));

        doc.Add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));

        PdfOutline root = pdf.GetOutlines(false);

        foreach (var item in col1)
        {
                        
            doc.Add(new Paragraph(item.Name));
            root.AddOutline(item.Name);
            doc.Add(new AreaBreak());
        }

        doc.Close();
        doc.Flush();
        pdfBytes = stream.ToArray();
    }

    return File(pdfBytes, "application/pdf", "test.pdf");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public ActionResult CreatePdf()
{
    byte[] pdfBytes;
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var wri = new PdfWriter(stream))
    using (var pdf = new PdfDocument(wri))
    using (var doc = new Document(pdf))
    {
        List<Destination> destinations = new List<Destination>();

        doc.Add(new Paragraph("Working with iText7"));

        // Iterate through your collection (col1) and add content and destinations
        for (int i = 0; i < col1.Count; i++)
        {
            var item = col1[i];

            Destination destination = PdfExplicitDestination.CreateFitH(i + 1, doc.GetPdfDocument().GetPage(i + 1));
            destinations.Add(destination);

            doc.Add(new Paragraph(item.Name));
            doc.Add(new AreaBreak());
        }

        PdfOutline root = pdf.GetOutlines(false);

        for (int i = 0; i < col1.Count; i++)
        {
            var item = col1[i];
            root.AddOutline(item.Name).AddDestination(destinations[i]);
        }

        doc.Close();
        doc.Flush();
        pdfBytes = stream.ToArray();
    }

    return File(pdfBytes, "application/pdf", "test.pdf");
}
```

Check this code. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**